# Does anyone have a good solution for documenting API's generated using Views REST export displays?

Tags: view, drupal-8, drupal-modules, openapi, documentation-generation

I have looked into the [OpenAPI module](https://www.drupal.org/project/openapi) for Drupal but views is not supported from what I can see.

https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_api_doc -> Seems too old/un-maintained